# GAE - Secure data Connector and Taskqueue/Cron

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to use the Secure Data Connector (SDC) to access internal resources in Tasks/Cron Jobs on the Google AppEngine?

The documentation speaks about the currently logged in user but does not further elaborate this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Offline' requests such as Task Queue tasks and Cron jobs have no 'user' as far as systems like SDC are concerned. If your SDC connection requires a logged in user, you will not be able to access it from a cron/task queue job.

Comment: There's a lot of folks clamoring for this feature...there's a [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-sdc/LUt-qhnu-NQ) about this